# Expiration Dates for Shares

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

Quick question:  In SharePoint Online, didn't there used to be a way to set expirations dates for share links?

I no longer see this option...

Answer (score 2):

This option should be in the SharePoint Online admin center, you may need to switch to the "Classic" admin center to see the option.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/09/set-anonymous-link-expiration-in-sharepoint-online.html

Answer (score 0):

Expiration dates is for sharing anonymous link. First you need to enable using anonymous links in admin center, then you can set the expiration dates when sharing links to anyone.

[image]